# Handlebars helper to return markup

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following very simple handlebars helper that returns an image url:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper 'avatarUrl', (property, options) ->
  if value = Ember.get(this, property)
    if small_url = value.small_url
      return small_url

  '/images/fallback/small_default.png'
```

Which I use like this:

```
<img src="{{avatarUrl avatar}}" title="displayName">
```

The above works but what I would like to do is return the entire img element.

Is this possible with a handleabars helper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (right at the bottom):

> If your helper returns HTML that you do not want escaped, make sure to return a new `Handlebars.SafeString`.

So if you want your helper to return a fully formed `<img>` element, then build your HTML string and wrap it in a `Handlebars.SafeString`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper 'avatarImg', (property, options) ->
  # Build your <img> HTML string and leave it in result ...
  new Handlebars.SafeString(result)
```

and then in your template you should be able to have:

```
blah blah {{avatarImg ...}} blah blah
```

and get an `<img>` out of your `{{avatarImg ...}}`.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the escape function is called `Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view to represent that image tag and then call handlebars view helper from within your custom helper. For example:

```
App.AvatarView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'img',
  attributeBindings: ['src']
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('avatarUrl', function(property, options) {
  var small_url, value;
  value = Ember.get(this, 'avatarUrl');
  if (value) {
    small_url = value.small_url;
  }
  var hash = options.hash;
  hash.src = small_url || '/images/fallback/small_default.png';

  Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.AvatarView, options);

});
```

I've posted a working example here: http://jsbin.com/adewot/1/edit

This is based on the way ember's own linkTo helper works. To see a more advanced example check out the source here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L83

Answer (score 2):

`import { htmlSafe } from '@ember/string';` for Ember 3 https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_escaping-html-content

`safeString` was deprecated in 2.8.0 and removed with 3.0.0
https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_use-ember-string-htmlsafe-over-ember-handlebars-safestring